# Why do the Tories keep Boris Johnson around?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit, conservative-party, boris-johnson

[Boris Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Johnson) is both a well-known and perennial figure in the British Conservative Party. Despite [his highly-educated background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Johnson#Eton_and_Oxford:_1977%E2%80%9387), he cultivates [a public personality likable to a bumbling-fool](https://www.newstatesman.com/politics/2015/06/bo-jos-blond-ambition-boris-bumbling-beginning-bore) while simultaneously courting and winning seats in positions of power.

What I don't understand is how, after a disappointing mayorship of London, he championed the cause of Brexit in opposition to [the majority of the conservative party's membership](https://www.express.co.uk/news/politics/820846/Brexit-EU-deal-Conservative-MPs-Remain-Theresa-May) - [at the time](https://www.verdict.co.uk/brexit-leaders-boris-johnson-brexit/) his leadership of the Pro-Brexit campaign was seen as [a precursor to Conservative Party leadership](https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-eu-johnson/johnson-reignites-leadership-speculation-with-brexit-plans-idUKKCN1BR0B1) - despite this seemingly politically contradictory position and his aforementioned public persona, he was hand-picked by Theresa May for the Foreign Secretary in her cabinet, and as of late December 2017 [is being considered for "ownership" of Brexit](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/12/31/david-davis-allies-fear-will-marginalised-boris-johnson-given/), despite most of the current Tory cabinet's historical opposition of separation from the EU.

- Why does the Tory party keep Boris Johnson around?
- How is he an asset to the party?
- How does the party leadership reconcile his aspirations of power with their own rational self-interest?
- What are the disadvantages to removing him from the Tory party?